# Updated JSON object shows in DOM and local storage but not when accessed through the chrome developer console?

Tags: javascript, json

In the following js fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aNQEy3, I am initializing an object. When you click `Update`, I am doing an ajax call and in the success call back I am updating the object with a new property and value.  I can see the object updated in local storage as well as the DOM, but when I type it in the chrome console, I don't see the updated value.  Here are more details:

Initialize the object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var localClientStorage = window.localStorage;

    var cartObj = {"one":"1","two":"2"};

    localClientStorage.setItem("cartObj",JSON.stringify(cartObj));

    $('#cartObj').text(JSON.stringify(cartObj));

</script>
```

After this runs, I see the folowing:

Local Storage:

[image]

DOM:

[image]

Console:

[image]

When I click the update function it runs the following code which gets the object from storage and adds a new value, but when I type "cartObj" into the console, it still shows the old value:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



        $(function(){


            $('.submit').click(function(){


                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="Update", controller="Home"})',

                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function() {


                            var localClientStorage = window.localStorage;

                            var cartObj = localClientStorage.getItem("cartObj");

                            cartObj = JSON.parse(cartObj);

                            cartObj.three = "3";

                            localClientStorage.setItem("cartObj", JSON.stringify(cartObj));                     


                           $('#cartObj').text(JSON.stringify(cartObj)); 
                                            }});

            });

        });

    </script>
```

After clicking update, the LocalStorage and DOM show the updated value `{"one":"1","two":"2","three":"3"}`, but the console only shows:

[image]

How can I show the updated value in the console?  I tried updating the content inside the script element with something like this to see if refreshing it would work, but it didn't:

```
$("#cartObj").load(location.href+" #cartObj>*","");
```

In order to see the output, you have to select mvc-output-iframe in the console.

Comment: When are you trying to query the console? IOW at what point in the code are you querying `cartObj` and finding it lacking?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - sorry, what  is IOW?

Comment: Sorry, "In Other Words".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - OK thanks, it looks like I just have to not declare a new variable when trying to update my global one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two variables `cartObj`. One global one created in your first snippet, which is the one you see in the console.

In your post callback you create another variable `cartObj`, which is local to the function scope and shadows the global one. It is destroyed once the function finishes execution. The global variable `cartObj` is not touched from the callback function.

Comment: Hi, so ids become global variables?  How would I be able to update the global variable?  Thanks so far.

Comment: Is it just a matter of not declaring a new variable?  Ah that seems like it.  Thanks for leading me in the right path.

Comment: @xaisoft To not declare a new variable, change `var cartObj` in your second code block to `cartObj`. This will reassign the global.

Comment: @tcoc - Thanks for the input.